# Trying to limit max char can be used in a Regular Expression

Tags: c++, regex

I have license plates that has to be checked if they are in the correct form.

Plate examples:

```
82AD8320
31ALK215
```

Correct form is 2 digits,1-4 chars, 2-5 digits relative to chars.

Idea is that they have to be maximum of 8 chars.

This is what i came up with as a regex:

```
^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1,4}[0-9]{2,5}$
```

I can't figure out how to limit the maximum amount of chars. In the regex i created, I can also use something like 35ALKS2313 and it will match. This is not what i want. What should i do?

Comment: If this is C++ as the tag suggests, please show the full/minimised C++ code needed to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: If you are using boost, you could use a lookahead `^(?=[0-9A-Z]{8}$)[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1,4}[0-9]{1,4}$` or perhaps you can check the string length upfront.

Comment: this is a general regex question, trying on c++, no code needed but i can fix the tag.

Comment: @Thefourthbird not using boost, just standard regex_match on cpp

Comment: @guacamolest There is not one canonical "regex", so it very much _does_ depend on what library (and hence language) you are using, whether any given syntax will work.

Comment: I would use multiple checks. One check for the length and one regex check for the format.

Comment: Not every possible predicate on strings should be coded as a regular expression match.